# Send data from Java to C++ Graalvm

Tags: java, c++, graalvm, polyglot

I'm working with GraalVM coding in Java and C++ as polyglot code. I have this code to print in C++ with Java:

**printMessage.cpp C++ code:**

```
#include <iostream>

int imprimemensaje(std::string s);

int main() {
    int imprimemensaje(std::string s);
    std::cout << "Hello, C++ World!" << std::endl;
    int a = imprimemensaje("Hola mundo c++");
}

int imprimemensaje(std::string s){
    std::cout << "Mensaje desde c++ : " << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and this code in **Java to execute C++ object using execute():**

```
File file = new File("printMessage");
Source source = Source.newBuilder("llvm", file).build();    
Value cpart = context.eval(source);
cpart.execute();
```

And print on screen this:

*Hello, C++ World!
Mensaje desde c++ : Hola mundo c++*

I need to call only **imprimemensaje()** function to send data from Java, I tried with *cpart.getMember("IDmember")* method, but it retrieves me a null value, also *cpart.getMemberKeys()* has no items on it.

Does anyone know why this happened or is there another way to send data to c++ object through Java? Thanks.

Comment: I think c++ by default mangles the names, so the member search doesn't find it. Maybe you can try it with: `extern "C" int imprimemensaje() {`, but I don't know the right answer

Comment: It does't work, but thanks. I change the language for C and create and .o executable. Now I can read it from context in Java GraalVM.